# How to group array value duplicate and customize the display of the results of the array in html table?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have here a for loop, $limit is the number of year (this is based on the sql database result).
In this case, the $limit is 3, the count of lid is 3 (1, 2, 3).
Then used another query to get all the values of the three lid, so there are 8 rows.
In the 8 rows, there are only 5 unique class id, I need to group the duplicate index of class ID.

I already tried array_unique to display the 5 results only. But I still need the values of the other 3 results to be able to display it in the p2 and p3 columns, but in the same row if they have the same class ID

```
<?php
   for($iy=1; $iy&lt;=$limit; $iy++){   
     $sql="SELECT * FROM view_items WHERE pyear='$iy'"
     $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
     $query->execute();
     $res=$query->fetch();  
     $lids = $res->lid;
     $sql_arr.="SELECT * FROM view_items WHERE lid='$lids'"; 
     if($iy!=$limit) $sqlarr .= " UNION "; 
     $new_arr[] = $sql_arr; 
   }
   $sql = implode("",$new_arr);
   $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
   $query->execute();
   $result = $query->fetchAll();

   foreach($result as $row):    
    $q1 = ($row->month1) + ($row->month2) + ($row->month3);
    $q2 = ($row->month4) + ($row->month5) + ($row->month6); 
    $total = $q1 + $q2;
?>
   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row->item_class; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $q1; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $q2; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $total; ?></td>
   <tr>
<?php 
  endforeach; 
?>
```

Instead of displaying 8 result, it should display only 5 rows.
Then the values of the duplicate should be on their right column based on their pyear.
It's a bit hard to explain in paragraph form, maybe the sample output will do explain better.

Actual output

[image: Actual Output (Wrong)]

Expected output

[image: Expected Output]

FINAL: Used SQL query instead of customizing the display of array. Answer for both my question (BUT THE QUESTION IS NOT A DUPLICATE), but still open for any suggestions regarding array since I'm no expert in that.
[How to display group_concat result seperately in html table cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56322476/how-to-display-group-concat-result-seperately-in-html-table-cell)

Comment: Why are the `Staff` and `Team Leader` values in the `P2` and `P3` columns?

Comment: your expected output is not understood. how to get p2 value and how to get p3 ? which logic perform to get this value to please describe on the question

Comment: Because the `P1` (project) contains only three items which are `leader`, `consultant` and `coordinator`. The `P2` have also three items (`leader`, `consultant` and `staff`) while the `P3` only have 2 items ( `leader` and `team leader`).

Comment: Each project may or may not contain the same items, this way I know the `P2` do not have the `coordinator` item and `P3` do not have the `consultant`, `coordinator`, and `staff`. I don't want to duplicate the row of class id. Did anyone get what I meant?

Comment: @Sumitpatel, all the values of P1, P2, and P3 will be from the sql query `SELECT * FROM view_items WHERE lid='1' UNION SELECT * FROM view_items WHERE lid='2' UNION SELECT * FROM view_items WHERE lid='3'` with a result of 8 rows. P1 have 3 items, P2 have 3 items, and P3 have 2 items, total of 8 rows.